# Radio buttons inside RecyclerView keep randomly being unchecked even when I explicitly set the checked state on a radio button

Tags: android, kotlin

To make ViewHolder treat each radio button separately and not reuse previous radio button's state I  stored the state of whether or not a radio button item is checked in a list of booleans and set the radio buttons state according to that list. but when I scroll down and up the toggled radio buttons get untoggled randomly even though the isCheckedList contains the right boolean information for each radio button(I print the list with logd() to verify if it actually stores the states)

Any Idea of what I'm missing?

```
class QuestionAdapter(context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<QuestionAdapter.QuestionViewHolder>() {

    private val listOfQuestion: List<String>
    private val listSize = 20
    private val isCheckedList: MutableList<Boolean> = MutableList(listSize) { false }

   //Initialize a list of 20 questions. 
    init {
        val allQuestions = context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.questions).toList()

        listOfQuestion = allQuestions
            .shuffled()
            .take(listSize)
    }

    class QuestionViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val questionText = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.question)
        val radioButton = view.findViewById<RadioButton>(R.id.yes)
       
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): QuestionViewHolder {
        val layout = LayoutInflater
            .from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false)
        return QuestionViewHolder(layout)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: QuestionViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val item = listOfQuestion[position]
        holder.questionText.text = item

        holder.radioButton.isChecked = isCheckedList[position]
        holder.radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
                isCheckedList[holder.adapterPosition] = isChecked
                Log.d("Adapter", "list: $isCheckedList ")
        }
    }
    
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listOfQuestion.size
    }


}
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me, buttons stay checked and none of them change on their own when scrolling (with the latest build of the ``recyclerview`` AndroidX library, ``1.2.1``)

Comment: Interesting, that's what I thought everything looks good with the code it should work fine and yes I have same library version!

Comment: If that is the exact code up there then I'm not sure, but if it isn't, make sure there isn't a weird interaction between setting a checked state, and the ``onCheckedChangedListener`` firing. Also are you sure you want radio buttons? You can't really toggle them off, and if you're trying to work around that, it might be introducing some weird behaviour

Comment: Yeah I'm using the exact code above and that's not the final code I wrote it simple for only one radio button per view just to make sure everything is working properly and then I was planning to add multiple radio buttons per view. Radio buttons are the right thing to use for my case because I want to allow only one answer per each question in the recyclerView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the selection on the radio button before setting its correct value.

```
holder.radioGroup.clearCheck()
```

This way, the `RadioGroup` clears its selection, ready to receive an input that will trigger the correct `RadioButton` as checked.

But you need to be aware that this might call your `onCheckedChanged` listeners and could bring unexpected outcomes. But there is a work around for the resulting problem.

```
// Nullify listener
holder.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

// Clear selection
holder.radioGroup.clearCheck();

// Reset listener after selection has been cleared
holder.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkedChangeListener);
```

Comment: Yes I discovered that I should add ```holder.radioGroup.clearCheck()``` but another problem appeared which is what you mentioned about the onCheckedChangeListener(), that listener get automatically used even though I don't click on any radio button and by Nullifying the listener as you said solved my problem thanks!

Comment: I am glad it was of help to you, you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding this line of code `holder.radioGroup.clearCheck()` before setting the state of radio buttons.
For more details this is a [blog](https://medium.com/android-ideas/using-radiogroup-in-a-recyclerview-c6d2861552db) talking about the same issue and how he solved it.